# Understanding callbacks in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am beginner in nodejs. I am trying to understand a bit of code. Basically it creates an event.

models/event.js

```
EventSchema.static("createEvent",function(event,user,callback){
var That = this;

async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        var time = moment(event.releaseTime).tz(event.releaseTimezone).utc().toDate();
        event.rTime= time;
        callback();
    },

    function(callback){
        var model = new That(event);
        That.validateEvent(model,user,function(err){
            if(err){
                callback({message:err});
                return;
            }else{
                callback(null,model);
                return;
            }
        });
    },

    function(model,callback){
        model.save(function(err,doc){
            if(err){
                callback({message:"Error saving event",err:err});
            }else{
                callback(null,doc);
            }
        });
    },

    function(savedEvent,callback){ /*Some further code is written here*/}
```

I have understood the first two callback functions but failed to understand the third & fourth one.

In second callback it says

`callback(null,model);`

and then the next callback starts with

`function(model,callback){`

In third callback it says

`callback(null,doc);`

and then next callback starts with

`function(savedEvent,callback){`

I am not understanding this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Admittedly, the first function in `waterfall` can be combined with the second one, since it's not asynchronous.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes could be optimised in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With waterfall, the first argument(s) of the second and subsequent functions is/are the return value(s) from the previous callback. Per the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-waterfall):

```
waterfall([
  function(callback){
    callback(null, 'one', 'two');
  },
  function(arg1, arg2, callback){
    callback(null, 'three');
  },
  function(arg1, callback){
    // arg1 now equals 'three' 
    callback(null, 'done');
  }
], function (err, result) {
  // result now equals 'done' 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> callback(null,model);
> ```

A function (stored in a variable named `callback`) is called. Two arguments (the value `null` and the value of the variable `model`) are passed to it.

> ```
> function(model,callback){
> ```

A function is defined. It expects to receive two arguments. The first argument will be stored in a variable named `model`. The second argument will be stored in a variable named `callback`.

---

The other call to a function and function definition work in much the same way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.